# Can't run Apache: Need to Find out which application is already using port 80 on my machine 

Tags: apache, windows-vista, port

I am trying run Apache web server on my computer without success, and I think it's because another application is using port 80 in my machine. I want to find out how to change the port that Apache uses or find out which application is already using port 80 so I can close it. Could somebody help me please?? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux and probably other Unix-like OSes:

```
$ netstat -n -l -p --inet --inet6 | grep :80
```

It will happily point out any process using port 80 on your server...

On Windows, one way to find out what is going on would be to go through the output of

```
netstat -n -a -o -p TCP
```

looking at the entries marked as `LISTENING`, then use the Process Manager to find out which process corresponds to the PIDs that match.

Comment: @thkala- Thanks, but I'm using windows Vista..what will work for that?

Comment: @thkala- Thanks, I found out which application was using port 80 and closed it, but Apache is still crashing for some reason. Any idea as to why?